# How to save inputs in association with their field labels?

Tags: javascript, html

The following script generates a series of input fields based on an array of strings. What I would like to due is have a button that saves the inputs in association with the field names. So ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'] might be associated with the inputs [bingo, bango, bongo, bungo]. Perhaps as a tuple [loren : bingo, ipsum : bango, plumbus : bongo, dumbas : bungo]? I'm really not sure about the best way to do this.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"/>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addFields(){
        var fieldNames = ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'];
            // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            
            for (i=0;i<fieldNames.length;i++){
                // Append a node with a random text
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fieldNames[i]));
                // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                input.name = fieldNames[i];
                container.appendChild(input);
                // Append a line break 
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
        }
        addFields();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using jQuery you could've used an awesome function called `serializeArray()` on a `form` element.

To keep this vanilla js:

1. I moved your array of fields outside the function.
2. Added a button called Get Values
3. Added an onclick on it to loop through your fields and add it to a javascript object.

Here is the onclick function:

```
document.getElementById('getValues').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var values = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        const element = fieldNames[i];
        values[fieldNames[i]] = document.getElementsByName(fieldNames[i])[0].value;
    });

    console.log(values);
}
```

Snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input id="getValues" type="button" value="Get Values" />

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var fieldNames = ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'];
    
    function addFields() {
      // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
      var container = document.getElementById("container");
      // Clear previous contents of the container
      while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        // Append a node with a random text
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fieldNames[i]));
        // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.name = fieldNames[i];
        container.appendChild(input);
        // Append a line break 
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
    }
    
    addFields();
    
    document.getElementById('getValues').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var values = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
            const element = fieldNames[i];
            values[fieldNames[i]] = document.getElementsByName(fieldNames[i])[0].value;
        }

        console.log(values);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your `fieldNames` element creation to also add a class of `fieldInput` - This is then used by the button to loop over all inputs created this way, and update a global object `fieldValues`

```js
let fieldValues = {};

function addFields() {
  let fieldNames = ['loren', 'ipsum', 'plumpus', 'dumbas'];

  // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
  let container = document.getElementById("container");

  // Clear previous contents of the container
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
    // Append a node with a random text
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fieldNames[i]));
    
    // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = fieldNames[i];
    input.className = 'fieldInput';
    container.appendChild(input);
    
    // Append a line break 
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}

// On button click, loop through inputs and assign values to the fieldValues Object
document.getElementById('saveFields').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.fieldInput').forEach((ele) => {
    fieldValues[ele.name] = ele.value;
  });

  console.log(fieldValues);
});

addFields();
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="saveFields">Save Fields</button>
  <div id="container" />
</body>
```